# Installing rEFind for Windows 7

Tags: linux, windows-7, uefi, refind

I'm trying to switch from Windows 7 to Arch Linux (used it in a VM for years now preparing to use it 100%).

First thing I'm doing is to have the computer boot using rEFind.

I tried to install it using the instructions on rEFind's website but they don't seem to work:

```
> bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi
The parameter is incorrect.

> bcdedit /set '{bootmgr}' path \EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi
The element data type specified is not recognized, or does not apply to the
specified entry.
Run "bcdedit /?" for command line assistance.
Element not found.
```

I also tried using Visual BCD Editor (v0.9.3.0, the latest version I could find) to change the `{bootmgr}` entries. Theres no `ApplicationDevice` `ApplicationPath` entry, and if I force it by adding an entry with 0x11000001, it doesn't get added:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I ended up just using the UEFI shell according to the [official instructions](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#efishell). I should've just used that instead of BCD, as BCD is a windows-specific thing.

rEFInd now boots up and shows my Linux entry, stored in another partition.